# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'width' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I always got an error in the object that I'm using. I also got an error of Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react'
import {Fab, TextareaAutosize} from '@material-ui/core'
import {ArrowBack} from '@material-ui/icons'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { QrReader } from 'react-qr-reader';

function QRscanner() {

    const [qrscan, setQrscan] = useState('');
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const isPlayingRef = useRef(false);

    function handleInputChange(event) {
        setQrscan(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleScan = data => {
        if (data) {
            setQrscan(data)
            const video = videoRef.current;
            if(isPlayingRef.current) {
                video.pause();
                isPlayingRef.current = false;
            }
            video.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
            video.play();
            isPlayingRef.current = true;
        }
    }

    const handleError = err => {
        console.error(err)
    }

    const onResult = async (data) => {
        setQrscan(data);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // wait for 5 seconds
        setQrscan('No Result');
    }

    function handleLoadedMetaData() {
        videoRef.current.play();
    }

    const fabProps = {
        style: {marginRight: 10},
        color: 'primary',
        width: 230
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/">
                <Fab {...fabProps}>
                    <ArrowBack/>
                </Fab>
            </Link>
            <span>QR Scanner</span>

            <center>
                <div style={{marginTop:30}}>
                    <QrReader
                        delay={300}
                        onError={handleError}
                        onScan={handleScan}
                        onResult={onResult}
                        style={{ height: 240, width: 320 }}
                    />
                    <video style={{ height: 240, width: 320 }} ref={videoRef} onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedMetaData}>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </center>

            <TextareaAutosize
                style={{fontSize:18, width:320, height:100, marginTop:100}}
                maxRows={4}
                value={qrscan}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
            />

        </div>
    );
}

export default QRscanner;
```

Comment: Please post the full error message in the question, and indicate which line is getting the error.